# Нарушение лексической сочетаемости

Tags: стилистика

В этих примерах нарушена лексическая сочетаемость.

Нарушение лексической сочетаемости (длинная заводская труба, высокая водосточная труба). 
В чем именно ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Длинная труба обычно ассоциируется с горизонтально лежащей, а заводская труба - обычно самостоятельная конструкция, возвышающаяся над зданием, в отличие от водосточной трубы. Габариты водосточной трубы определяются высотой здания (она прокладывается от крыши); если назвать её "высокой", создаётся впечатление, что она вертикально поставлена и стоит где-то сама по себе. Поэтому более естественно говорить о высоком здании с водосточной трубой (если она чем-то примечательна).

Comment: Но здесь надо исправить именно эти примеры.

Comment: Можно, например, поменять местами "длинную" с "высокой", хотя и трудно придумать подходящее прилагательное для водосточной трубы (если абстрактно говорить, то лучше назвать её напр. "крашеной", чем "длинной").

Comment: @ Alex_ander, я тоже об этом думал.